# Using a secured WCF service through a client

Tags: wcf, security, certificate

I am using a secured WCF service in a client appliction. My problem is when I hit the https: url directly on the browser , it asks to select a certificate and it runs fine but through a client application I am getting error :
     `Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'server name'`
Can anyone please explain this behavior
Thanks

Comment: did you specify a client certificate in you wcf configuration?

Comment: And before the certificate, did you also specify a security mode ?

Comment: yes i specified security mode as transport as it is in the service itself and yes I specified a client certificate in wcf configuration.But it is still not working